# how to specify facebook scope during registration

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am using the complete code below to register a user to my site. Where would I specify what permissions I want during registration? I try putting it before the fields variable and that did nothing. Thanks.

```
            <?php
            define('APP_ID',"848483");
            define("REDIRECT_URL","some url");

            ECHO'
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
            <head>     
            <meta content="noarchive" NAME="robots">
            <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            </head>
            <body>

            <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?
                             client_id='.APP_ID.'&
                             redirect_uri='.REDIRECT_URL.'&
                             fields=
            '."
            [{'name':'name'},{'name':'email'},{'name':'username','description':'my site username','type':'text'},{'name':'password'}]".'"
                      scrolling="auto"
                      frameborder="no"
                      style="border:none"
                      allowTransparency="true"
                      width="100%"
                      height="330">
            </iframe>
             </body>
            </html>
            ';
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
&scope=permission,permission,etc,etc
```

after your fields param

Comment: I tried what you said to publish a stream but I still get an error: "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

Comment: Does anyone else have an idea of how to request permission from facebook? I am using this link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/